# Get Single Property out of array without "@{"

Tags: arrays, powershell

Ok So I am pretty new to powershell and I can import a csv file that doesn't have any headers. (I manually add it in) My array looks like this.

```
Servers
Plab2
192.168.10.204
```

When I loop through the array instead of being able to grab "Plab2" or "192.168.10.204" I get "@{Server=Plab2}" or "@{Server=192.168.10.204" Is there any way just to grab the value "Plab2" or "192.168.10.204"?

Here is my code

```
$list = Import-Csv $inputFile -Header Server
For($i=0; $i -le $List.Count -1; $i++){
$b = $List[$i][0]
Write-Host $b
}
```

Comment: Substitute `$b = $List[$i][0]` with `$b = $List[$i][0].Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$list = Import-Csv $inputFile -Header Server
$list | Foreach-Object { Write-Host $_.Server }
```

Note that

```
$list | Foreach-Object { Write-Host $_.Server }
```

can be abbreviated as

```
$list | %{ Write-Host $_.Server }
```

Also if this is not something that is called from another script (i.e. you don't mind returning items from the pipeline), you can write this line like this:

```
$list | %{ $_.Server }
```

Comment: Note that `%{ Write-Host $_.Server }` is not the same as `%{ $_.Server }`. The difference becomes apparent when you assign the result back to a variable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: No, it is not the same. `$_.Server` returns the result to the pipeline, `Write-Host $_.Server` sends it to the host (such as console).

Answer (score 3):

The format you get is because each object in the array is an object with the property "Server"(as specified in `-Header Server`.

Your file isn't a csv-file. A csv file has properties(like name and ip) for the same object on ONE row, seperated by a delimiter(ex a comma `,`). So you could do one of the following:

Read the file as pure text using `Get-Content` and pick out the elements (name and ip)

```
$arr = Get-Content $inputFile
$arr[1]
$arr[2]

Plab2
192.168.10.204
```

You could access the `Server` property of each object in the loop to get the value.

```
Import-Csv $inputFile -Header Server | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Server
}

Servers
Plab2
192.168.10.204
```

You could also rewrite your file to proper csv-format, ex:

csvfile:

```
ServerName,IP
Plab2,192.168.10.204
```

script:

```
Import-Csv $inputFile | % {
    $_.ServerName
    $_.IP
}

Plab2
192.168.10.204
```